# How can filter Every result in datagridview according to string i typed on text field in C#

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, datagridview

I want to search raws in `DataGridView`when I type a letter in a`TextBox`. I have 4 columns(Log_ID, userId, LogTime, Date)

What I want is when I type any string in the `TextBox`, all the results containing that string should be displayed. How can I do this?

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far, including your (Perhaps simplified) `datagridview`. This will allow people to help you better.

Comment: post what have you tried

Answer (score 0):

well i think that the data when you retrieved't into the datagridview, should filter the data, it should be in the textchange of your textBox, well, i made some like this, on a past project, this code could be an example with the simple way to make this. As follow, you should be know that, i used EntityFramework, so the access to data for me was more easy.

```
  private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string a = textBox4.Text;
        Filtrar(a);
    }

    private void Filtrar(string cad)
    {

        if (cad.Length > 0 && cad.Length < 12)
        {
            var queryFB = from b in obj.beneficiarios
                          where b.beneficiario_ci.IndexOf(cad) != -1
                          select b;

            dataGridView1.DataSource = queryFB;          
        }
        else
        {
            if (cad.Length == 0)
            {
                dataGridView1.DataSource = obj.beneficiarios;
            }
        }

    }
```

Hope this Helps.